# Scrolling away the Browser UI before scrolling through overflow content?

Tags: html, css, svelte

I want to have a website that has a fixed navbar at the top of my page, and the rest of the content should be scrollable.

I can achieve that using this setup:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/Y31avA7qZq?size=502x680

```html
<main class="flex flex-col text-foreground">
    <nav class="fixed w-full h-24 bg-black">Nav.</nav>
    <div class="h-[calc(100vh-6rem)]">
        <div class="mt-24 h-[calc(100vh-6rem)] overflow-y-scroll">
            <slot />
        </div>
        <footer class="min-h-24">Footer.</footer>
    </div>
</main>

<style>
   html {
     @apply bg-gradient-to-b from-red-500 to-red-900 bg-fixed;
   }

   body {
     @apply min-h-[100dvh];
   }
</style>
```

This works great, and in mobile devices, it looks like you're scrolling the browser UI away before you start scrolling through the content. However, I do have one small gripe with this solution: the scrollbar appears from the very top of the page (which means, the scrollbar appears over the navbar, which doesn't look like it's scrollable content). The behaviour is demonstrated in a screen recording here: https://i.imgur.com/zjf778G.mp4 (I tried converting the videos into a gif, but they were still too large for file upload here)

Just for prettyness, I would like to somehow constrict the scrollbar to the bottom of the navbar and the bottom of the viewport.

I tried to restrict the part below the navbar and make only that overflow scroll, like so: https://play.tailwindcss.com/H3hLu7Hpee?size=502x680

```html
<main class="text-foreground flex flex-col">
  <nav class="fixed h-24 w-full bg-black">Nav.</nav>
  <div class="h-[calc(100vh-6rem)]">
    <div class="mt-24 h-[calc(100vh-6rem)] overflow-y-scroll">
      <slot/>
    </div>
    <footer class="min-h-24 bg-red-500">Footer.</footer>
  </div>
</main>

<style>
  same as above
</style>
```

However, this results into two scrollbars, one for the page, one for the content, and, when you scroll in the bottom part, you have to scroll all the way to the end of the content before the 'actual' page continues scrolling and hides the browser ui. This is of course expected behaviour, so this can't be a solution to the problem: https://i.imgur.com/Fpgbsqt.mp4

So now I'm wondering, what is the best way to approach this?

Is it possible to either

- Scroll overflow content only when the browser ui is hidden
- Constrict the visual looks of the browser scrollbar so that it looks like it only starts below the navbar

Or is my only solution to:

- Hide the browser scrollbar and make a custom element myself ?

https://i.imgur.com/Fpgbsqt.mp4

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this what you are looking for but anyway. I have changed the height to `h-[calc(100vh-12rem)`. This removes the outer scroll. Check it->

https://play.tailwindcss.com/oxO3eiaGrV?size=534x522

If you don't want that sticky alike footer, then keep the height to `h-[calc(100vh-6rem)` and move the footer up into the content's `div` like -

https://play.tailwindcss.com/qhWsOuMcAP?size=534x522

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the same issues exist in the code you posted.

In the first link, the scrollbar still appears over the navbar.
In the second link, the code seems to be the same exact code as I already have in my second example?

Comment: @KamielDev For the first link, here, on my laptop the scrollbar doesn't appear over the navbar. For the second link, yes it is your code. I just moved the footer up in the content div. This makes the footer a part of the scrollable content, so its height doesn't cause overflow in the viewport and as result, the outer scrollbar disappears.

Comment: Ah I see. I just tried both your solutions on a self-hosted server, and you're right in that they both make sure that the scrollbar is restricted to the content div. I want the footer in the scroll area, so I prefer your second solution. If you simulate a mobile viewport on the browser, it looks like it's all working - but if you go visit the project on an actual phone (not in tailwind play, but hosted), the behaviour is the same as in the second video I posted, where you have to scroll through the entire content div before being able to scroll away the browser UI...

Comment: (cont...) That is expected behaviour and their entire purpose - you are not supposed to be able to scroll the page when you're scrolling in a scroll view.
That's why I'm trying to look for a way to either 'fake' the scrollbar to appear below the navbar, or prevent the overflowed content from scrolling when the viewport isn't 100vh.